# PyTorch convert function for op 'len' not implemented for coremltools

Tags: pytorch, coreml, coremltools

I am trying to convert my model in Core ML with Coremltools. I had some issue that I replicated in this simple example.

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import coremltools

class SimpleTest(nn.Module):
    def forward(self, x):
        value = len(x)
        return torch.tensor(value)

simple_model = SimpleTest()


scripted_model = torch.jit.script(simple_model)
mlmodel = coremltools.converters.convert(scripted_model, inputs=[coremltools.TensorType(shape=(400,))], debug=True)
```

*Console*

[image]

*debug=True produces this output in console*

```
the following model ops are IMPLEMENTED:
  constant
  tensor
the following model ops are MISSING:
  len
```

As you can see I have an error that tells that "PyTorch convert function for op 'len' not implemented."
I have two questions:

1. The `len()` is a Python function. Why does it try to convert to a PyTorch `len()` function?
2. Should I implement some custom converters to fix this errors using "register_torch_op"?

Maybe you have other suggestions how to avoid this kind of error?

Comment: General advise: When you are posting an error message, please post the full error traceback, not just one line.

Comment: This is clearly `coremltools` problem. Can you file an issue directly on their repo ?

Comment: @ayandas I haven't found any issue about it in github repo.

Comment: No. I am asking you to create an issue yourself. Their core developers can help your faster.

Comment: @ayandas yes, I've just create. Link: https://github.com/apple/coremltools/issues/1340

Comment: @AlexanderKarpov, try change to: value = x.shape[0]

Comment: @DmytroHrebeniuk Thanks for the suggestion. I use len() and other built in python function many times in different contests of my model. So I would like to know if it's possible to use this build in functions or I should choose other way to manage it.